# JQuery UI Widgets with AJAX requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I'm doing some geolocation/map work and building a JQuery widget so that the code is nice and portable for future projects.

I've run into a wall as far as making an AJAX request though; here's a couple of the methods from my widget:

```
    getGeocodeForAddress: function(address) {    
    req = this._googleMapsApiRequest('geocode','json','address='+address);

    //We need 'req' to be the response from the API request so we can do work with it.

},


/**
* Private Maps API request method. This will help to construct a call to Google Maps API.
* 
* @param service
* @param output
* @param params
*/
_googleMapsApiRequest: function(service,output,params) {

    var widget = this;
    var protocol = (this.options.useHttps) ? 'https://' : 'http://';

    if (this.options.googleMapsApiKey != '') {
        params += '&key' + this.options.googleMapsApiKey;
    }        

    var uri = protocol + 'maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/' + service + '/' + output + '?' + params;
    this._sendToLog("Google Maps API Request: " + uri);

    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        url: encodeURI(uri),
        success: function(response) {                
            //We need the contents of response to be available to the method that called this one.
        },
        error: function() {
            widget._sendToLog('AJAX error');
        },             
    });


},
```

The specific problem is that once the ajax request is made and returns its success, I can't get the data back into the method that calls it.

I've tried setting an internal option using widget.options.ajaxResponse in _googleMapsApiRequest but that seems to only be 'null' in the calling method, I've tried returning the response from inside the AJAX method but that doesn't work either.

I'm sure I need a callback in the _googleMapsApiRequest method so that it will wait for that method to complete and I can then execute code based on that, but how can I do that within a widget?

Answer (score 0):

A break to think about something else and then a bit more research and I have come up with a callback solution.... it seems a bit clunky but it seems also to do the trick, can anyone improve on it?

```
    getGeocodeForAddress: function(address) {    

    this._googleMapsApiRequest('geocode','json','address='+address, function(response)
    {           
      //I can access response within this callback.
    });

},


/**
* Private Maps API request method. This will help to construct a call to Google Maps API.
* 
* @param service
* @param output
* @param params
*/
_googleMapsApiRequest: function(service, output, params, callback) {

    var widget = this;
    var protocol = (this.options.useHttps) ? 'https://' : 'http://';

    if (this.options.googleMapsApiKey != '') {
        params += '&key' + this.options.googleMapsApiKey;
    }        

    var uri = protocol + 'maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/' + service + '/' + output + '?' + params;
    this._sendToLog("Google Maps API Request: " + uri);

    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        url: encodeURI(uri),
        success: function(response) {                
            widget._sendToLog('AJAX success, response follows');
            widget._sendToLog(response);
        },
        error: function() {
            widget._sendToLog('AJAX error');
        }             
    }).done(function(response) {
        if (typeof callback == "function") {
            callback(response);
        }
    });
},
```

I haven't tested yet to see how this handles unsuccessful ajax requests, but it does the trick at least when the request works.